# Polymorphic Functors in OCaml (related to Include command)

Tags: include, ocaml, functor

EDIT: I replaced abstract example with module type A and B by a more concrete example using groups and rings.

I present my problems with functors on an example using well-known algebraic structure. Define a signature for groups:

```
module type Group = 
sig
    type t
    val neutral: t
    val add: t -> t -> t
    val opp: t -> t
end
```

And define a signature for groups that contains many useful operations, e.g. here conjugation:

```
module type Extended_Group =
sig
    include Group
    val conjugate: t -> t -> t
end
```

Implementation for conjugation depends only on addition and opposite, so I don't want to write it explicitly for all groups I define, so I write the following functor:

```
module F (G: Group) =
struct
    include G
    let conjugate x y = add (add x y) (opp x)
end
```

Now, suppose you are working with other structures that "extend" the notion of group, for instance the ring of integers:

```
module Z = 
struct
    (* Group *)
    type t = int
    let neutral = 0
    let add x y = x+y
    let opp x = -x
    (* Ring *)
    let m_neutral = 1
    let mult x y = x*y
end
```

Since a ring is a particle case of group, we can apply functor F to it:

```
module Extended_Z = F(Z)
```

Unfortunately, to apply F to Z, Ocaml first restrict the type of Z to Group, and then apply F.
Everything behaves exactly as if I did this:

```
module (Group_Z: Group) = Z
module Extended_Z = F(Group_Z)
```

And thus, eventhough Z.mult makes sense, Extended_Z.mult is unknown to the compiler. I don't want to lose the fact that Extended_Z is still a ring ! Of course, the solution that consist in writing a functor F_Ring that does just like F but taking a Ring as input is not a satisfying one: I don't want to write F_Fields, F_VectorSpace, and so on.

Here is what I would want:

1. Either a way to extend the signature of a module, to expose more values. 
   It is possible to do it the other way, restricting the signature of a module (with the syntax I used for Group_Z), but I can't find a way to enlarge a signature. Here it would be something like:

   ```
   module (Ring_Extended_Z: Ring) = Extended_Z
   ```
2. Or, a way to define polymorphic functors, that is defining a functor F that takes a module
   of signature "at least Group" and output a module of signature "at least Extended_Group". Of course, 
   this makes sense only in presence of include, which is why I strongly believe such a feature does not exist in OCaml.

After searching for several days for answers on the Internet, I think the correct way to achieve this is actually the following one:
(Inspired from chapter 9 of Real World OCaml)

```
module F (G: Group) =
struct
    let conjugate x y = ...
end
```

(same as previously but without the include)
and then perform all the includes at the same point:

```
module Extended_Z =
struct
    include Z
    include F(Z)
end
```

Can someone confirm that this is the good way to achieve what I want, and that my first approach does not fit
the spirit of OCaml ? More specifically, can someone confirm that options 1. and 2. are indeed impossible in OCaml ?

EDIT: Concerning dynamic typing

It seems to me that this is still static typing, since if I write

```
module Extended_Z = F(Z: Ring)
```

OCaml could still type this statically as a module that has signature Ring with the extra value "conjugate". It requires polymorphism at the module level, 
which I understand does not exist, but I think it could exist without making the type system dynamic.

Comment: afaict functors are always monomorphic. they have a definite type that is known at compile time. therefore e.g. a functor defined by Id (A) = struct include A end cannot be made to accept any module A, since the input type has to be known. see here: http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/modules.html#sec211 . if you look up the definition of a module type you will find that there is no equivalent of a polymorphic variant for modules, i.e. no notion of 'at least these values' for a module type.

Comment: I completely understand that modules are monomorphic, but the include command gives the impression that such a functor Id can be made. Define module type Empty = sig end, and module Id (A: Empty) = struct include A end; you will be able to apply functor Id to any module A, at the price of forgetting everything that A contains.

Comment: i see. i agree that include would make it appear that you can include just anything but in fact what you include must appear as a functor argument with a definite signature (as you know). anyway, see the proper answers below

Answer (score 2):

Functors are abstractions over structures, that produce structures from structures. In fact, they are categorical morphisms, i.e., arrows. This is a very powerful mechanism, but still has a restriction: all parameters of a module must have a fixed (constant) module type, i.e., there are no module type variables. That means, that it is impossible to get what you want and sometimes you will need to write more code, than you expect.

Your example actually captures an idea of least (minimal) structure and greatest (maximal). The former distills the minimal requirements for an algebraic structure, while the latter describes a maximal set of elements, that can be derived from it (where elements are represented as structure fields). Compare it with Haskell's type classes, where you provide a minimal implementation and the rest is derived by a type class definition. The same, can be expressed with functors, but unlike Haskell there is no machinery that will apply this functors automagically, you need to instantiate all functors manually. This is in line with OCaml ideology - explicit is better than implicit. (Although, the upcoming modular implicits will diverge from this ideology by providing similar inference mechanism as Haskell's type classes).

But enough words, let's do some coding. As I said, your example, poses a great example for minimal and maximal structures. We will start by defining minimal requirements for corresponding algebraic structures trying to follow the definitions closely:

```
module Min = struct
  module type Set = sig
    type t
    val compare : t -> t -> int
  end

  module type Monoid = sig
    include Set
    val zero  : t
    val (+) : t -> t -> t
  end

  module type Group = sig
    include Monoid
    val (~-) : t -> t
  end

  module type Ring = sig
    include Group
    val one : t
    val ( * ) : t -> t -> t
    val (~/) : t -> t
  end
  ...
end
```

We put all module type definitions into module `Min`, that denotes, that they are minimal. These are only module types, i.e., signatures.

Now, we can define a maximal signatures. Here a problem is that it is usually hard to stop, i.e., to find the greatest fixpoint. But this is not a big problem, as you may continue to write functors that takes smaller structures and returns bigger until you're satisfied with a result.

For example, we can infer lots of things just from having type t and the `compare` function:

```
module Max = struct
  module type Set = sig
    include Min.Set
    val (=) : t -> t -> t
    val (<) : t -> t -> t
    val (>) : t -> t -> t
    module Set : Set.S  (* this is Set from stdlib, not ours *)
    module Map : Map.S
    (* and much more *)
  end

  module Ring = sig
    include Min.Ring
    ...
  end
  ...
end
```

Now, when we have a nice theory of structures, we can move to the implementation. We can provide a generic morphisms  `Min.T -> Max.T` for all signatures `T`, e.g.,

```
module Set(S : Min.Set) : Max.Set with type t = S.t = struct
  include S
  let (<) x y = compare x y = -1
  ...
  module Set = Set.Make(S)
  module Map = Map.Make(S)
  ...
end
```

Using these generic functors as basic instruments, and our minimal definitions we can build a structure for a real type, that we're defining. Moreover, since generic functors are often not able to provide optimal implementation for some operations, we can provide our own, that will leverage our knowledge of the implementation. For example:

```
module Z = struct
  module T = struct
    type t = float
    let compare = compare
    let one = 1.
    let zero = 0.
    let (+) = (+.)
    let (~-) = (~-.)
    let (~/) x = (1. /. x)
  end
  include Set(T)
  include Ring(T)
  (* override minus and division as we can implement them more efficiently *)
  let (-) = (~.)
  let (/) = (/.)
end
```

And we can describe a module type of our concrete `Z` module very easily, by just including corresponding maximal signatures plus adding our specific stuff:

```
module type Z = sig
  include Ring
  val read : in_channel -> t
  val write : out_channel -> t -> unit
end
```

### About module level polymorphism

It was noted in the comments by Andreas Rossberg, that OCaml module sub-language actually allows polymorphism at least syntactically. This is a system F style polymorphism that must be introduced explicitly by `L` term, a term that binds types instead of values. Since modules can carry types, we can express `L` term with a module that has the following module type:

```
module type L = sig module type T end
```

Now, we can define classical polymorphic functions, `id`, `fst` and `snd`:

```
module Id(L:L)(X:L.T) = X
module Fst(L1:L)(L2:L)(M1 : L1.T)(M2 : L2.T) = M1
module Snd(L1:L)(L2:L)(M1 : L1.T)(M2 : L2.T) = M2
```

However, it looks like that we're very limited in what we can do with our parameters in the right hand side of a functor definition. For example, we cannot combine two modules:

```
module Sum(L1:L)(L2:L)(M1 : L1.T)(M2 : L2.T) = struct
  include M1 
  ^^^^^^^^^^
  Error: This module is not a structure; it has type L1.T
  include M2
end
```

We also can't open modules, as we're getting the same error. The problem is that `include` and `open` statements are evaluating a module type variable to its value, expecting to get a signature. Since a typing environment doesn't yet have a binding for the `L1.T` we got a, kind of misleading, error message. Given this limitation, we can only work with parameters on the identifier level. For example, we still can define the `Sum` module as:

```
module Sum(L1:L)(L2:L)(M1 : L1.T)(M2 : L2.T) = struct
  module X = M1
  module Y = M2
end
```

It is very questionable, whether it has any practical usage, though. Another example would be to define `App` functor, that will apply a functor to the argument (also of dubious usability):

```
module App(L1:L)(L2:L)
 (F : functor (X : L1.T) -> L2.T)(X:L1.T) = struct
  module R = F(X)
end
```

Comment: It is not true that OCaml modules are "monomorphic". In fact, they can be entirely polymorphic. Here is the polymorphic identity functor: `module F (T : sig module type T end) (X : T.T) = X`. But yes, they don't provide row polymorphism (which OTOH wouldn't be powerful enough to handle `include` anyway).

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer. 
I have edited my question to make clearer what I am looking for.

For the first part of your answer: Does working with classes instead of modules solves my problem ?
I am not sure that what I want necessarily requires dynamic typing, see my edit.

Comment: For the second part, I understand that this example is the canonical one to 
explain how to use include, but it does not answer my question since it does not show any interaction with functors (see my edit).
In the case I only want to extend some existing structure (e.g. Monads) I think the following would work as well:

    module type Extended_Monads = 
 sig
  Include Monad
  Extra Stuff
 end

and in an implementation, I just have to provide code for the extra stuff, possibly using functions from module Monad.

Comment: @AndreasRossberg, this is more of terminology, they are monophonic as each type is constant, i.e., there is no type variables. Also, your example is not a polymorphic identity functor, but a functor that creates an identity functor for the specified type signature.

Comment: @SimonHalfon, nice edit, now it makes much more sense to me (sometime it is hard to get the idea from a pure syntactic examples, involving names A,B,C, that's why I chose a monad and computation, but algebraic structures are better). Concerning your note about dynamism, you're absolutely right (I actually meant a different thing, but my wording was bad). I will update my answer to reflect your updated question.

Comment: "Does working with classes instead of modules solves my problem ? I am not sure that what I want necessarily requires dynamic typing", nope classes are of now help there, moreover they are very static in a sense.

Comment: @ivg, `T.T` is your type variable. The only moral difference is that this is explicit polymorphism (System F style), not implicit polymorphism (ML style).

Comment: @AndreasRossberg I have played around with your example, it is indeed polymorphism ! I didn't know you could put a signature into a module structure, but in a sense, a signature is just a module's type and you can define types in a module so ... It might be just what I need, I'll keep you informed. Thank you. Should I put an edit on my question to show what implementation your solution suggests on my example (for people who would later wonder the same question) ?

Comment: @AndreasRossberg, yep if you put it this way, then it would be polymorphism. The updated answer no longer makes this false statement.

Comment: @SimonHalfon, I've updated my answer with results of my experiments with this system F-style polymorphism. If you have better results, I will be happy if you will share them. You're welcome to edit the answer, if you like.

Comment: @SimonHalfon, yes, although it's worth noting that there is a serious catch: treating module types analogous to ordinary types that way actually makes type checking OCaml undecidable. ;)

Comment: @ivg, the reason that you cannot `include` a module of type `L.T` is that it simply is an abstract type. Just like you cannot use `+` on an abstract value type. Somebody might in fact instantiate the functor with a module type that isn't a structure (e.g., a higher-order functor)... Not sure what point you're making in the last sentence btw., this is again no different from e.g. System F, where you'd also apply the type separately and get back a monomorphic function.

Comment: What I'm trying to emphasize is that there is a difference between term application `F(X)` and Lambda term elimination `F[X]`, as well as there is a difference between functor abstraction and Lambda term introduction . They have different reduction rules, i.e., different semantics. For example, in module abstraction OCaml reduces term types before the application. In real system F, this reduction would be delayed. But, I agree, that even if it would be a real system F, we still will not have an option to `include` or `open` parameters, since this operations are only defined for structures.

Comment: @ivg, thank you for updating your answer. Unfortunately, I experienced the same limitation as you when I tried to use include. Knowing that it is impossible, I can only try to approximate what I wanted to do, and I am not sure which approximation is best. The min-max structure framework does not fit me, as I don't know a priori the biggest structure I will later encounter.

Answer (score 2):

I share in this answer the two partially-satisfying solution I have found to implement what I wanted.

The first one is the one suggested at the end of my question, and in the case of algebraic structure is probably the "good" one.

```
module type Group = 
sig
    type t
    val neutral: t
    val add: t -> t -> t
    val opp: t -> t
end

module type Extended_Group =
sig
    include Group
    val conjugate: t -> t -> t
end

module F (G: Group) =
struct
    let conjugate x y = G.add (G.add x y) (G.opp x)
end

module type Ring = 
sig
    include Group
    val m_neutral: t
    val mult: t -> t -> t
end

module Z = 
struct
    type t = int
    let neutral = 0
    let add x y = x+y
    let opp x = -x
    (* Ring *)
    let m_neutral = 1
    let mult x y = x*y
end

module Extended_Z = 
struct
    include Z
    include F(Z)
end
```

In this case, the signature of Extended_Z inferred by OCaml "extends" the signature Ring, and indeed Extended_Z.mult is visible outside the module.

The second solution uses pieces of what Andreas Rossberg and Ivg suggested to simulate polymorphism at the module level. It is less satisfying in the case of algebraic structure, but for my actual problem it is just perfect.

```
module type Group_or_More =
sig
    include Group
    module type T
    module Aux: T
end

module F (G: Group_or_More) =
struct
    include G
    let conjugate x y = add (add x y) (opp x)
end


module Z = 
struct
    type t = int
    let neutral = 0
    let add x y = x + y
    let opp x = -x
    module type T = 
        sig
            val m_neutral: t
            val mult: t -> t -> t
        end
    module Aux = 
        struct
            let m_neutral = 1
            let mult x y = x*y
        end
end


module Extended_Z = F(Z) ;;
```

Here, the signature Group_or_More captures exactly this idea that I had of a signature extending another. You put everything extra into the auxiliary module Aux. But, in order to be able to provide as many auxiliary functions as one wants, you specify the signature of this Aux module as part of your group.

For algebraic structure, it is less satisfying since Z and Extended_Z are rings in a weaker sense: multiplication is accessed by Z.Aux.mult and Extended_Z.Aux.mult.

Comment: Nice, your solution is actually a module level equivalent of a polymorphic record, c.f., with `type ('a,'aux) group_or_more = {  neutral : 'a; ..; aux : 'aux}`. In fact I still don't understand actually what you're looking for, maybe if you will be able to express your requirements not in terms of a language, but semantically, we will be able to find a better solution. I have a feeling, that all this is an abuse of the language.

Comment: I would gladly share with you the details of what I am trying to achieve, but I don't want to saturate this question with irrelevant matter. What is the usual way of achieving this ? Should I post another answer that we delete afterward or can we share email adresses ?

Comment: Semantically, I think what I want is a notion of subtype / supertype but for modules, so more like super-signature and sub-signature; and then a way of casting a module (does this make sense ?)

Comment: If you put it this way, then the first thing that comes to my mind is subclassing. You can take an arbitrary class of type `<x;y>` and inherit from a class of type `<a;b>` to get `<a;b;x;y>`. The roadblock that you may hit, is that you need to know the type of the base class, and when you inherit, you can only inherit a fixed set of fields, i.e., you can't take a class of type `<a; b; ...>` and inherit methods `a`, `b` and all others.

Comment: This is too much restriction for me. In my case, I have a module type WQO, and many modules of type WQO. All of these WQOs have different auxiliary functions, specific to the WQO. And I want to be able to access these auxiliary functions from outside. I know this is the opposite of what signatures are for. This is why the solution of putting all auxiliary functions in a submodule, whose signature can be different from a WQO to another seems perfect to me.